# Unable to install Mongo DB drive for C# in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mongodb, wcf

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I am trying to install MongoDB driver through NuGet 'Package Manager Console'. When I type the command **'Install-Package mongocsharpdriver'** I get the following message and error. (Please read the very last few lines of the message I pasted for the actual error message). I could not find anything specific related to this in the internet. Could someone help me identify the cause of this issue. I am executing the above command inside a WCF service solution.

> PM> Install-Package mongocsharpdriver 'MongoDB.Bson (≥ 2.0.0)' not
>   installed. Attempting to retrieve dependency from source... Done.
>   'MongoDB.Driver.Core (≥ 2.0.0)' not installed. Attempting to retrieve
>   dependency from source... Done. 'MongoDB.Driver (≥ 2.0.0)' not
>   installed. Attempting to retrieve dependency from source... Done. You
>   are downloading MongoDB.Bson from MongoDB,   Inc., the license
>   agreement to which is available at
>   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Check the package for
>   additional dependencies, which may come with their own license
>   agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes
>   your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the
>   license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your
>   device. Successfully installed 'MongoDB.Bson 2.0.0'. You are
>   downloading MongoDB.Driver.Core from MongoDB,   Inc., the license
>   agreement to which is available at
>   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Check the package for
>   additional dependencies, which may come with their own license
>   agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes
>   your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the
>   license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your
>   device. Successfully installed 'MongoDB.Driver.Core 2.0.0'. You are
>   downloading MongoDB.Driver from MongoDB,   Inc., the license agreement
>   to which is available at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
>   Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with
>   their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and
>   dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements.
>   If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the
>   relevant components from your device. Successfully installed
>   'MongoDB.Driver 2.0.0'. You are downloading mongocsharpdriver from
>   MongoDB,   Inc., the license agreement to which is available at
>   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Check the package for
>   additional dependencies, which may come with their own license
>   agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes
>   your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the
>   license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your
>   device. Successfully installed 'mongocsharpdriver 2.0.0'.
>   Install-Package : Unable to find assembly references that are
>   compatible with the target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'. At
>   line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  mongocsharpdriver
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Update:

I realised that the version of NuGet package was old, so I installed the most recent Version (Version 2.8.60318.667). I tried to install the driver after the new version of NuGet was installed, but getting the same error message. I am only pasting the error part below. It is worth noting that, the error message says that the package is not compatible with .NET framework 4.0. I tried .NET framework 3.5 and 3.0,but I got similar error message.

> Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Could not install
>   package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package
>   into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Ver sion=v4.0', but the
>   package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
>   are compatible with that framework. For more information, co ntact the
>   package author. At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  mongocsharpdriver
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 5):

I have understood the cause of this issue and solution. The problem is with the version of the Mongodb C# driver I am trying to install. The latest version of MongoDB C# driver (version 2.0) is not supported for .NET framework 4.0!. I came to know about the supported .NET versions from the following link.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

version 2.0 driver only supports .NET framework 4.5. For same strange reason, there is not .NET 4.5 version support for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (I am shocked!).

**Resolution:**

I installed MongodB C# driver version 1.10, by executing the following command. There was no issue this time and the driver installed smoothly.

Install-Package mongocsharpdriver -Version 1.0.0

Comment: Get the VS Community Edition 2013 so you can use .Net 4.5 [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). It gives you everything of the previous VS professional editions for free.

Answer (score 0):

These are the dependencies:

1. MongoDB.Bson (≥ 2.0.0)
2. MongoDB.Driver.Core (≥ 2.0.0)
3. MongoDB.Driver (≥ 2.0.0)

Comment: I tried to install MongoDB.Bson first. This also gave me the error ''MongoDB.Bson 2.0.0' already installed Install-Package : Unable to find assembly references that are compatible with the target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  MongoDB.Bson
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Try the other ones. MongoDB.Driver

Comment: I have also tried 'MongoDB.driver' 'MongoDB.Bson' and 'MongoDB.Driver.Core'. All in different sequence, but every time I see the same error. (Strange to see the message '..already installed..'. I do not see any package!)

Comment: try Install-Package mongocsharpdriver -force

Comment: Also try Tools->package Manager->Package Manager Settings-> Clear Package Cache

Comment: executed with "force" option. Got error "Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'force".  There is no "Clear Package Cache" in Visual Studio 2010 IDE.

Comment: Its -Force not -force

Comment: I used '-Force' and '-force'. Both are giving the same error.